Does `row_number() over ()` have any guarantees when called on an in-memory dataframe?
If I run
duckdb.sql('select *, row_number() over () as index from df')

on a pandas/Polars dataframe, then does the row number always enumerate the rows in order of appearance?
This seems to be the case:
In [11]: df = pl.DataFrame({'a': range(1, 1_280_000)}); duckdb.sql('select *, row_number() over () as index from df qualify a != index').pl()
Out[11]:
shape: (0, 2)
┌─────┬───────┐
│ a   ┆ index │
│ --- ┆ ---   │
│ i64 ┆ i64   │
╞═════╪═══════╡
└─────┴───────┘

but is it something which can be relied upon more generally?

while in general SQL is unordered unless order by is specified, it seems that in duckdb there's some effort to keep rows in a same order - order preservation. That's said, I'd probably avoid using row_number() without order by in production.

There's also a bit vague documentation here: ...Ordering is also optional, but without it the results are not well-defined....

thanks - I think I'll call with_row_index on the Polars dataframe before passing it to duckdb just to be safe then
